# Образуют ли функции Базис

Tags: дискретная-математика

**Условие задачи**:
Во входном файле заданы несколько функций. Образуют ли они базис? Сначала во входном файле записано число - количество функций, далее все функции, каждая в отдельной строке.

**Идея**:
Сперва вспомнил определение базиса. Функции образуют базис, если они не входят ни в одну из замкнутых классов и система функций является полной, т.е если убрать одну из функций то это уже не базис.

Далее расписал все функции для замкнутых классов(T0, T1, L, M, S), также функции all_plus и plus_minus() - нужны для того чтобы определить есть ли строка или столбец где '+' и '-' соответственно.

А далее функции check которая проверяет по несколько функций. Сначала по 2 потом по 3.

Вроде бы все верно, но выдается ошибка на одном из тестов(автоматическая система проверок), есть одна гипотеза где именно.

Скорее всего ошибка тут(в 186 строке): `if(i == l or l == j) continue;` Может быть надо or поменять на and либо добавить на след. строке проверку `i == j`.

А Вы что думаете?

**Код:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int n, m;
int i, j, k;
string *arr;
bool **post;

void t0()
{
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i][0] == '1') post[i][0] = false;
        else post[i][0] = true;
    }
}

void t1()
{
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i][k-1] == '0') post[i][1] = false;
        else post[i][1] = true;
    }
}

string pyramid(string val)
{
    string tmp = "";
    
    for(j = 0; j < k; j++)
    {
        tmp += val[0];
        
        for(int p = 0; p < k-1; p++)
        {
            val[p] += val[p+1]-48;
            if(val[p] == '2') val[p] = '0';
        }
    }
    
    return tmp;
}

void linearity()
{
    string tmp;
    int power;
    
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        power = 0;
        tmp = pyramid(arr[i]);
        
        for(j = 1; j < k; j++)
        {
            if(j == pow(2, power))
            {
                power++;
            }
            
            else if(tmp[j] == '1')
            {
                post[i][3] = false;
                break;
            }
            
            post[i][3] = true;
        }
    }
}

void self_double()
{
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < k/2; j++)
        {
            if(arr[i][j] == arr[i][k - 1 - j])
            {
                post[i][4] = false;
                break;
            }
            
            else post[i][4] = true;
        }
    }
}

void mono()
{
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < k/2; j++)
        {
            if(arr[i][j] > arr[i][j + k/2])
            {
                post[i][5] = false;
                break;
            }
            
            else post[i][5] = true;
        }
    }
}

bool all_minus()
{
    int count = 0;
    
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            if(post[i][j] == false) count++;
        }
        
        if(count == 5) return true;
        else count = 0;
    }
    
    return false;
}

bool all_plus()
{
    int count = 0;
    
    for(j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if(post[i][j] == true) count++;
        }
        
        if(count == 5) return true;
        else count = 0;
    }
    
    return false;
}

bool check2()
{
    int count = 0;
    
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if(i == j) continue;
            
            for(int p = 0; p < 5; p++)
            {
                if( post[i][p] == true and
                    post[j][p] == true and
                    n == 2) return true;
                    
                else if(post[i][p] != post[j][p]) count++;
                
                else if( post[i][p] == false and
                         post[j][p] == false) count++;
            }   
            if(n != 2 and count == 5) return true;
            else count = 0;
        }
    }
    
    return false;
}

bool check3()
{
    int count = 0;
    
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if(i == j) continue;
            
            for(int l = 0; l < n; l++)
            {
                if(i == l or l == j) continue;
                
                for(int p = 0; p < 5; p++)
                {
                    if( post[i][p] == true and
                        post[j][p] == true and
                        post[l][p] == true and
                        n == 3) return true;
                        
                    else if( post[i][p] != post[j][p]
                          or post[i][p] != post[l][p]
                          or post[j][p] != post[l][p]) count++;
                          
                    else if( post[i][p] == false and
                             post[j][p] == false and
                             post[l][p] == false) count++;
                }
                if(n != 3 and count == 5) return true;
                else count = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    ifstream fin("input.txt");
    ofstream fout("output.txt");
    if(!(fin >> n)) {fout << 0; return 0;}
    if(n == 0 or n > 4) {fout << 0; return 0;}
    
    if(n == 1) {fout << 1; return -1;}
    
    arr = new string[n];
    
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 2; j++) fin >> m;
        fin >> arr[i];
    }
    
    k = pow(2, m);
    post = new bool*[n];
    
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        post[i] = new bool[5];
    }
    
    t0(); t1(); mono(); self_double(); linearity();
    
    if(all_minus() == true) {fout << 0; return 1;}
    if(all_plus() == true) {fout << 0; return 2;}
    
    if(check2() == true) {fout << 0; return 3;}
    if(check3() == true and n > 2) {fout << 0; return 4;}
        
    fout << 1;
    return 0;
}
```